# Force Text Visualiser to ignore null terminate charcters and show the all bytes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, watch

I have a following code:

```
std::string buffer("68\r\n\x2\x2\0\0\0\0\0\x3\x1G\0attributes-charset\0\x5utf-8H\0\x1ttributes-natural-language\0\x5en-us!\0\x13notify-get-interval\0\x4\0\0\0\x1e\x5\x3\r\n", 100);

return 0;
```

And I would like to see this content in Text Visualizer via Visual Studio 2019 while debugging.

[image]

Is it possible to force somehow the Text visualizer to show the whole content and tell it manually how long the text is? Something like in the watch window it is shown but unfortunately that's a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. You could not change the parsing characters output of text visualizer. And text visualizer have to identify the null terminate characters and use it. You could only change [the format of the data UI display in text visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2019).